# Prove that a permutation representation of a simple group is either faithful or trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, representation-theory

I need help on this question.
Prove that a permutation representation of a simple group is either faithful or trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The kernel of a homorphism is a normal subgroup.  Simplicity then implies that the kernel is everything or nothing.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with it being a permutation representation...